# How to debug shaders running on Android 4.x devices?

Tags: android, shaders, opengl-es2, debugging

I have tried some of the existing inspectors such as RenderDoc and gapid, but none of them can be used with Android 4.x. Latest version of gapid requires Android 6.0 and RenderDoc requires Android 5.0.

But I need to debug shaders in my app running on a Galaxy Tab 3 8.0 (SM-T311, ARM Mali 400), which uses Android 4.2.2. I cannot upgrade its Android version.

The app was made with Unity 2018.4 and targets Android 4, ARMv7. How can I inspect & debug my shaders running on this kind of device?

Comment: I have been trying to find an old version of them that supports Android 4.x but still not found.

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks. I'm actually trying to figure out what is happening on that device when a certain mesh is rendered.

Comment: If that's important to understanding your question, then use the edit button to put it into the question itself, not in a comment addressed to me.

Comment: @DMGregory Nope. I just want to say thank you to you :D